# systemd's [ok] and [fail] at the beginning of the line

Tags: centos, systemd

I have got to re-write heaps of boot scripts for a variety of servers of mine because of upgrading from CentOS 6.X (SysVinit) to CentOS 7.X (systemd).

There is a file "/etc/rc.d/init.d/function" that contains a number of functions that handle the printout for "[ok]" and "[fail]". There are called "echo_success" and "echo_failure". They are still part of the latest version (compatibility) but they print the [OK] and [fail] at COL 60, not at COL 0.

All other boot up scripts/daemons show the [OK] and [FAIL] at the beginning and then the [UNIT] Description.

How do I achieve this using existing functions that are part of systemd?
Does systemd handle this and I just need to return "fail" and "ok"?
But how?

This is especially tricky if you use "ExecStart" and "ExecStop".
Do I just dump error info to the logs and not print anything but only return "success", "fail" and "warning"?

What are the values of "success", "fail" and "warning"?

thanks